# Xamarin: Not able to run app on an iOS 9.2.1 device

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin

I'm an IOS developer in Xcode, but I still new to Xamarin environment ..

In **Xamarin Studio** on mac, I'm trying to run a **single view app** on my iPad, using [this tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/) ...

But when I choose to run the app.. it gives me these two errors :

> Error: Could not locate the iOS '9.2' SDK usr path at
>   '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.2.sdk'
>
> Error: Error executing task DetectSdkLocations: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: path1

---

Here are some informations about what I'm using

The iPad is running `IOS 9.2.1`

Xamarin Studio: `Version 5.10.2`

Xamarin.iOS: `Version 8.10.0.303`

Xcode: `Version 7.2.1`

And the **SDK locations** in Xamarin preferences are set properly

[image]

---

So where is the problem ?? and can I run the app on iPad with **IOS 9.2.1** ??

Thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not have access to the 9.x version of **IOS** until the 9.x.x.x version of **Xamarin.IOS**

Comment: The latest Xamarin.iOS version is 8.1.... Does that mean I can't run the app on device with IOS larger than 8.1 ??

Comment: @MujtabaFathel The latest Xamarin.iOS is Version: 9.4.1.25

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ... I don't know why Xamarin tells me that I'm up to date when running (Check for updates)

Comment: Please only post content in English.